# In Django, my request.session is not carrying over...does anyone know why?

Tags: python, django, session

In one view, I set:

```
request.session.set_expiry(999)
request.session['test'] = '123'
```

In another view, I do:

```
print request.session['test']
```

and it cannot be found. (error)
It's very simple, I just have 2 views.

It seems that once I leave a view and come back to it...it's gone! Why?

Comment: Have you read this? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/  Try to set a test cookie (innstructions below http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-object-guidelines)

Answer (score 18):

Could it be related to this?, just found it at http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes

Appending to a list in session doesn't work 
Problem

If you have a list in your session, append operations don't get saved to the object.
Solution

Copy the list out of the session object, append to it, then copy it back in:

```
sessionlist = request.session['my_list']
sessionlist.append(new_object)
request.session['my_list'] = sessionlist
```

Comment: Amazing. It was really weird for me, because whatever I would do it would only save 1 or 2 items in a list or dict. The last item would change, but it wouldn't let me add more than 2.

Answer (score 1):

Are you, by any chance, setting the session itself to an empty dictionary, somewhere?

Comment: This was exactly the cause for me